# RESET button is not working with input type file component

Tags: jquery

I have a input type file component in the form  and i am using Jquery Validation to validate the form

After uploading a image and clicked on **RESET** button

i am getting the following error under server console

```
VM111 jquery-1.11.0.js:4618 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(^|\.)bs\.(?:.*\.|)fileinput(\.|$)/: Stack overflow(…)
```

and from there on the **Jquery validation fails for the image** .

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
        $('#pacinsertform').validate(
        {
                rules:
                {
                        pacname:
                        {
                                required: true
                        },
                        previewpic: 
                        {
                         required: true
                        }
                },
                messages:
                {
                        pacname:
                        {
                                required: "NAME required",
                        },
                           previewpic: {
                           required: "User pic required",
                                }
                },
                highlight: function(element)
                {
                        $(element).parent().addClass('error')
                },
                unhighlight: function(element)
                {
                        $(element).parent().removeClass('error')
                },
                submitHandler: function(event, validator)
                {
                        if ($("#pacinsertform").valid())
                        {
                                ajaxInsertPac();
                                return false;
                        }
                }
        });
});

function ajaxInsertPac()
{
        alert('ajax call heer');
        return false;
}
```

This is my fiddle

Could you please let me know how to fix this issue .

http://jsfiddle.net/Luf0ks9b/38/

Comment: code working fine for me. please check you cache in browser

Comment: cleared cache same issue , i am using chrome browser .

Comment: i tried http://jsfiddle.net/Luf0ks9b/38/ in chrome browser, it works.

Comment: Not sure if jQuery 1.x has good support for regex, try upgrading to 3.x or at least 2.x.